# How to correctly create a new instance of class A when you gather information about it through events?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have a:

```
class A{
int val1, val2, val3}
```

In the other class I have

```
 static void eventA(int val1){ //invoked somewhere
  EventManager eventManager1 = new EventManager();
  eventManager1.ServiceResolved += new Events_ServiceResolvedEventHandler(eventB);
 }

 static void eventB(int val2){
  EventManager eventManager1 = new EventManager();
  eventManager1.AddressInfoFound += new Events_AddressFoundEventHandler(eventC);
 }

 static void eventC(int val3){
   //CODE
 }
```

Those events are only invoke in the order: eventA, eventB, eventC. In the eventA I have access to the val1, in the eventB I have access to the val2 etc. 
**How should I instatize object of class A in this class?**

---

EDIT:

```
    uusing Bonjour;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HomeSecurity {
    class Scanner {
        public static DNSSDService service;
        public static DNSSDEventManager eventManager;
        public static DNSSDService browse;

        public static void ScanService() {
            try {
                service = new DNSSDService();
                eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
                eventManager.ServiceFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceFoundEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceFound);
                browse = service.Browse(0, 0, "_axis-video._tcp", null, eventManager);
                //   Application.Run(form = new PumpingForm());
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }



        static void eventManager_ServiceFound(DNSSDService browser, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string serviceName, string regtype, string domain) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------- eventManager_ServiceFound------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("browser: " + browser + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifIndex " + ifIndex + "\nserviceName: " + serviceName + "\nregtype: " + regtype + "\ndomain: " + domain);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

                //   DNSSDService service2 = new DNSSDService();
                eventManager.ServiceResolved += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceResolvedEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceResolved);
                browser.Resolve(flags, ifIndex, serviceName, regtype, domain, eventManager);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION--------eventManager_ServiceFound---------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }

        private static void eventManager_ServiceResolved(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string fullname, string hostname, ushort port, TXTRecord record) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------eventManager_ServiceResolved---------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("DNSSDService " + service + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifindex " + ifIndex + "\nfullname " + fullname + "hostname " + hostname + "\nport " + port + "\nrecord " + record);
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(record.GetValueForKey("macaddress"));
                Console.WriteLine("mac " + str);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

                //    DNSSDService service2 = new DNSSDService();
                eventManager.AddressFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_AddressFoundEventHandler(eventManager_AddressFound);
                DNSSDAddressFamily family = new DNSSDAddressFamily();
                service.GetAddrInfo(flags, ifIndex, family, hostname, eventManager);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION--------eventManager_ServiceResolved---------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }

        private static void eventManager_AddressFound(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string hostname, DNSSDAddressFamily addressFamily, string address, uint ttl) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("------------------eventManager_AddressFound----------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("hostname " + hostname);
                Console.WriteLine("address " + address);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----eventManager_AddressFound------------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Private variable to store value of val1 passed to eventA?

Comment: You should not... all your methods are static so they shouldn't have any context - as result there is no place to store information between events. You need to figure out an entity that can store shared context information between events and it may be good place to create `A` when all information is collected.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I need at least `http port`, and `ip address` to create object of `class Camera`. First is gathered by `EventManager_ServiceResolved` second by `eventManager_AddressFound` and I do not know how to deal with that problem. Please look at the edit.

Comment: This doesn't make a great deal of sense. Why the separate events?

Comment: Yoda, have you tried to explain structure of your program to yourself (or [rubber duck](http://litemind.com/solve-your-problems-simply-by-saying-them-out-loud/) if needed)? Why for example you have 3 "event managers"? What does it may to have more than one? There really not much can be done in your current structure short of adding more static fields (which can't be really suggested as "answer" here to avoid spreading of bad coding practices).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov those events(AddressFound, ServiceSolved) are defined by Apple's `Bonjour` that's why they are seperate in my program.
I will use one Event Manager as private static field and then refer to it. How that would simplify my task? 
 Could  you maybe show this bad practice if nothing else could be done?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Could you look at the edit please. I have created only one `EventManager` as a static field(those fields has to be static -> other topic). Is there any possibility sole the problem now?

Comment: I've posted how one can solve it... there is no `static` so it probably will not work for you...

Answer (score 0):

You could have A with a default constructor, then have 3 functions to initialize val1, val2 and val3. I would then have a 4th function to ensure that all three values are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Here is rough sample how one can listen to 3 event in sequence and collect data (i.e. in dictionary) for first several events:

```
class MyEventListner 
{
    Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public MyObject Data {get;private set;}

    void HandleEvent1(EventData eventData) { fields["Field1"] = eventData.Field;}
    void HandleEvent2(EventData2 eventData) { fields["Field2"] = eventData.FieldFoo;}
    void HandleEvent3(EventData eventData) { 
       Data  = new MyObject { 
          Field1 = fields["Field1"],
          Field2 = fields["Field2"],
          Filed3 = eventData.Field
    }
}

MyEventListner listener = new MyEventListner ();
WhateverEventManager eventManager = new eventManager();

void Subscribe()
{
    eventManager.OneEvent += d => listener.HandleEvent1(d);
    eventManager.OtherEvent += d => listener.HandleEvent2(d);
    eventManager.LastEvent += d => listener.HandleEvent3(d);
}
```

after `LastEvent` fired  `listener.Data` will have filled out data object. One may want to notify someone (i.e. via another event) that `Data` is ready.